# Spring Data ArangoDB get parent directly with the annotation

Tags: graph, spring-data, arangodb

Here is my parent-child mappings

**Parent**

```
@Document("parents")
public class NodeParent extends CommonBo {

  private String name;

  @To(lazy = true)
  private List<RelationChildOf> childsOf = new ArrayList<>();

  ...
}
```

**Relation**

```
@Edge(value="childof")
public class RelationChildOf {

  @From
  private NodeChild child;

  @To
  private NodeParent parent;

  ...
}
```

**Child**

```
@Edge(value="children")
public class NodeChild extends CommonBo {

  ...
}
```

How can I modelize and retrieve with derived queries the parent inside a child?

I cannot see it inside the demo code https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data-demo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a child by its parent names, you can use `@Relations` instead of `@To` (see [docs](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/blob/master/docs/Drivers/SpringData/Reference/README.md#relations)). This way you don't have to receive the edge `RelationChildOf` in your application.

```
public class CommonBo {
  @Id
  private String id;
}

@Document("parents")
public class NodeParent extends CommonBo {
  private String name;
}

@Document(value = "children")
public class NodeChild extends CommonBo {
  @Relations(edges = { RelationChildOf.class }, lazy = true)
  private final List<NodeParent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The find method in the repository interface has to use the names of the field `parents` in `NodeChild` and the field `name` in `NodeParent`. `findBy`-`Parents`-`Name`-`(String)`

```
public interface ChildRepository extends ArangoRepository<NodeChild> {
  NodeChild findByParentsName(String name);
}
```

Usage:

```
  @Autowired
  ParentsRepository parentsRepository;

  @Autowired
  ChildRepository childRepository;

  @Autowired
  ChildOfRepository childOfRepository;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    NodeParent parent = new NodeParent("John");
    parentsRepository.save(parent);

    NodeChild child = new NodeChild("John Junior");
    childRepository.save(child);

    RelationChildOf childOf = new RelationChildOf(child, parent);
    childOfRepository.save(childOf);

    NodeChild childOfJohn = childRepository.findByParentsName("John");
    assertThat(childOfJohn.name, is(child.name));
  }
```